# UBUNTU commands to find file in a folder

Tags: command-line, server, find

I want to find files in a certain folder with certain extension, lets say finding "**.sql**" in "**/backup-nfs**". Later on, I will use this command on crontab to delete some files automatically.

I use 3 different methods and they give out different results :

Method 1 :

- login as A USER.
- go to **/backup-nfs**
- type in `ls -lah`
- Results are 14 files. Of course, this is correct.

Method 2 :

- login as A USER.
- go to **/backup-nfs**
- type in : `find . /backup-nfs/ -name "*.sql" -type f -ls`
- Results are 14 files (7 of them are duplicates, so essentially only resulted 7 files). Eg : ***file A, file B, ... file G, /backup-nfs/file A, /backup-nfs/file B,... /backup-nfs/file G***

Method 3 :

- login as A USER
- go to root of that user
- type in : `find . /backup-nfs/ -name "*.sql" -type f -ls`
- Results are too many files. It searches the whole directory, not just /backup-nfs !

Question:

1. Why did Method 2 only result in just 7 distinct files? There are 7 other files, with size 0KB, that are omitted.
2. Why does Method 3 search the **/backup-nfs** and also the entire directory **outside "/backup-nfs"** even though I have specified to search to only "`/backup-nfs`" ?
3. What's the correct method? I do not want to delete other files that do not meet the criteria.

I tried on Ubuntu 12.04 (server) and 20.04 (non server)

Comment: The `.` will translate to the current working directory … So you must not use it in method 3 and you don’t need to use it in method 2 … What do you mean by duplicates? Are there subdirectories in the search directory ? … Are you sure the release of Ubuntu is 12.04 ?!

Comment: Hi Raffa. I updated the question. Please kindly read the update. @Raffa

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is EOL thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 12.04 ESM was in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2017/03/15/ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-reaches-end-of-life-on-april-28-2017/

Comment: isn't it a general question, applied to all Ubuntu regardless of the version? @guiverc

Answer (score 6):

The problem is :

```
find . /backup-nfs/
```

You ask to search in `.` (the current directory) and also in `/backup-nfs`. If you want to search only in `/backup-nfs` just say it, no need to add the current directory.

```
find /backup-nfs
```

Answers:

1. No idea. You probably did not look right.
2. because you explicitly ask to search the current directory (`.`) that happens to be USER's home and `/backup-nfs`.
3. `find /backup-nfs -iname "*.sql" -print0 | xargs -0 rm`
   or as @terdon suggests in a comment, use the `-delete` action directly
   `find /backup-nfs -iname "*.sql" -delete`

---

Also note that you claim that `ls - lah` gives the correct result, this would mean that you have a folder named `-` and a folder named `lah` inside the folder `/backup-nfs` that together hold 14 files named "*sql". I seriously doubt that.

Comment: isn't `-lah` an option for `ls` ? Here : https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/ls.html @exore

Comment: `-lah` **is** an option. but "`-`space`lah`" are 2 arguments that are not options, thus regular arguments.

Comment: Yes..sorry for the typo. I just realize.. thanks @exore

Comment: No need for `xargs`, you can just do `find /backup-nfs -iname '*.sql' -delete`.

Comment: Oh. great. I still use the old idioms I learnt years ago. this `-delete` action is even better. Thanks @terdon.

Comment: Yeah, the `-delete` is a GNU `find` thing, if you're coming from the UNIX world it won't be familiar.